# How To apply a texture to QUAD_STRIP in opengl?

Tags: opengl

Well i am trying to apply a texture to 2 squares, but I only can  apply to the first one.

I am using the primitive QUAD__STRIP to draw the squares. Heres de code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);  glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, -1.0f* size, 0);    //1
            glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);  glVertex3f(-1.0f* size,  1.0f* size, 0);   //2
            glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);  glVertex3f(1.0f* size, -1.0f* size, 0);   //3
            glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);  glVertex3f(1.0f* size,  1.0f* size, 0);//4
                                    glVertex3f(3.0f* size,  -1.0f* size, 0);//5
                                    glVertex3f(3.0f* size,  1.0f* size, 0);//6
```

```
    glEnd();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see this line of code:

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);  glVertex3f(-1.0f * size, -1.0f* size, 0);    //1
```

the first statement, *glTexCoord2f()* specifies which point of the texture to hook up to the specified vertex (*glVertex3f()*). 
For each vertex you have to tell which point of the texture to map to it.

It might be usefull for you to look here: [GameDev.NET - OpenGL texture mapping: An introduction](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article947.asp)
Especially the part of "The texture coordinate system".

Hope this helps!

*edit, try http://nehe.gamedev.net/ as well! alot of OpenGL tutorials/articles, tutorial Lesson 6 has texture mapping in it. :) 
(Although it's not a very good example of good coding practice)

Comment: That's what SO's for! Have fun! And if you get something neat going I'd love to see it. :)

Comment: Sure, I am doing a project to a course of this semester. When is finished I will be happy to show you :)

Comment: Nice, you can find my contact details through my site. (lower right is a "contact" link). Good luck with the project and your course!

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting texture coordinates for the last 2 vertices (5 and 6) on the second quad.